# Error inserting data into SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, database, vb.net, ado.net

I receive the following error when executing my code to insert data into my database:

> system.data.oledb.oledbexception (0X80040E14): syntax error in insert
>   into statement

Here is my code:

```
   Public Sub put_data(ByVal lstpart As List(Of String), lstpartid As List(Of String), lstmanufacturer As List(Of String), lstmanufacturerid As List(Of String), lstprice As List(Of String), lstpartdescription As List(Of String), ByVal lstpartimg As List(Of Image))
        Dim intCurrentRecord As Integer = 0
        Dim strSQL As String
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        ' Dim sqlcmd As OleDbCommand

        MsgBox(MyCn.State.ToString, vbOK, "test")

        Try

        Do While intCurrentRecord <= lstpart.Count - 1
                strSQL = "Insert into Parts (Part, [Part ID],Manufacturer,Prices,[Manufacturer ID],[Part Description] VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)"

            strSQL = strSQL.Replace(vbCrLf, " ")

            Using MyCn
                Using sqlcmd = New OleDbCommand(strSQL, MyCn)
                    sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", lstpart(intCurrentRecord))
                    sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", lstpartid(intCurrentRecord))
                    sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", lstmanufacturer(intCurrentRecord))
                    sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", lstprice(intCurrentRecord))
                    sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5", lstmanufacturerid(intCurrentRecord))
                    sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6", lstpartdescription(intCurrentRecord))
                        sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                End Using
            End Using
            intCurrentRecord += 1

            Loop
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString, vbOK, "Error")
        End Try
        dbclose()
```

Comment: You have a syntax error in insert into statement. Your list of columns is missing a `)`, at least. Does `Using MyCn` mean that `MyCn` will be `Dispose`'d at that `End Using`? Because you seem to be re-using `MyCn` (`Do While ...`).

Comment: Seems like you're missing a `)` at the end of the column list.

Comment: yes I iterate through a few lists containing data inserting the data into each row.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a closing parentheses in the field list.  This:

```
Insert into Parts
(Part, [Part ID],Manufacturer,Prices,[Manufacturer ID],[Part Description]
VALUES
(?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

should be this:

```
Insert into Parts
(Part, [Part ID],Manufacturer,Prices,[Manufacturer ID],[Part Description])
VALUES
(?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

Comment: Ok so I found the issue in my syntax, one of those duh moments however when I go to pull the data it is coming back as the table having no data. Not sure why that is. I get no errors when putting the data in however an getting no data out. is there anything I need to do at the end of putting the data in, in order to ensure that the file is saved with the new data?

Comment: Got it figure out finally, I used  
sqlcmd.CommandText = strSQL
sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
dbTrans = MyCn.BeginTransaction()
dbTrans.Begin()
dbTrans.Commit()
dbclose()

and it now works.